# Css animation random delay

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to build a webpage for a comic studio and I want one of the characters to come in from the side every so often. So far I have this in the css

```
        .charc {
            animation:peek 20s infinite;
            left:-500px
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes peek{
            1% {transform:translateX(-500px)}
            10%{transform:translateX(100px)}
            20% {transform:translateX(-200px)}
            100% {transform:translateX(-500px)}
        }
```

and the html

```
<img src="character.jpg" class="charc"/>
```

This means the character comes on over and over again. I don't know whether it is possible to get random figures in CSS but I thought if it is, You guys would know

p.s. I know this will only work in chrome but I will be changing that soon.

Comment: Use js/jQuery to randomly repeat animation. Css does not have random numbers generator

Comment: what would the code be

Comment: Sass has a function where you can get random numbers.

Comment: @NiZa I did something like that for LESS one time to give my placeholders variety. It didn't work out so well. :P It would only change on a new compile, which is obvious to me now but makes using a preprocessor to do your random number generation kind of useless until browsers can support those languages natively.

Comment: To clarify what NiZa and Joseph said: Sass, LESS, etc can *generate* a random number when building the stylesheet, but once the resulting CSS is passed to the browser it's a static value. The OP needs a changing value, which currently still requires Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use js/jQuery for that.

```js
    function move() {
      $('.charc')
        .animate({
          left: '-500px'
        }, 200)
        .animate({
          left: '100px'
        }, 400)
        .animate({
          left: '50px'
        }, 400)
        .animate({
          left: '-500px'
        }, 100, function() {
          var nextIn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
          setTimeout('move()', nextIn);
        })
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      move();
    });
```

```css
#scene {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}
.charc {
  position: absolute;
  left: -500px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scene">
  <div class="charc"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with js :

```
    var divElement = document.getElementsByClassName("charc")[0];
    var maxValue = 20; //the random value won't exceed 20s
    function randomTime(maxvalue){
      return Math.round(Math.random() * maxvalue );
    }
    function changeAnimationTime(maxValue){
       var random = randomTime(maxValue);
       divElement.style.animation = "peek "+randomTime+"s infinite";
       setTimeout(function(){
           changeAnimationTime(maxValue);
       },random);
    }

    changeAnimationTime(maxValue);
```

The advantage of this methode is that you won't use js for animation but just for generating values. So it consumes less ressources.

Comment: Because `divElement` is a NodeList, whether it contains one or more modes, this will result in an error, you first have to specify which single node should be used in the function, or iterate over the supplied NodeList.

Comment: You're right David, I didn't test my code and to be frank I use a lot jquery. That's why I forgot to do that.

Comment: btw, you can also just set the individual animation properties with `divElement.style.animationDuration = randomTime+"s"` or `divElement.style.animationDelay = randomTime+"s"` (depending on what flavor you're going for) and leave the animation name and iteration count up to the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Not a random delay but you can use a tool I created called [WAIT! Animate](https://waitanimate.wstone.uk/) to add a pause between animations. Here's your animation with a 2 second pause between animations:

```
.peek.wait2.animated {
  animation: peek-wait2 22s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%
}
@keyframes peek-wait2 {
  0% { transform:translateX(-500px) }
  9.09091% { transform:translateX(100px) }
  18.18182% { transform:translateX(-200px) }
  90.90909% { transform:translateX(-500px) }
  100% { transform:translateX(-500px) }
}
```

Use [WAIT! Animate](https://waitanimate.wstone.uk/) to change the pause duration.

PS. I suggest starting at 0% to avoid a flicker in the animation.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question (as you acknowledge), but your animation calculator looks pretty useful. I especially like the example animations you provide; will bookmark that for future use.

Comment: link is dead :(

Comment: @fudge fixed the links :)